# libGDX: Why doesn't Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed() work?

Tags: java, libgdx, input

I'm trying to use the method Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed() to check if the Android BACK button was just pressed. I don't want to use the Gdx.input.isKeyPressed method to avoid multiple calls. Here is my code:

```
public void handleInput() {
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.BACK)) {
         // show previous screen...
    }
}

public void update(float dt) {
    handleInput();
}
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: This does work. Put a breakpoint inside `handleInput()` and see if the code is even reached, it's probably not and your missing a call to it somewhere deeper down the line.

Comment: @MennoGouw If I replace isKeyJustPressed() with isKeyPressed() it's working. The problem seems to be with the isKeyJustPressed() method.

Answer (score 1):

Below code works for me, I get the message when pressing the back button.

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.BACK))
        {
            Gdx.app.log("Debug", "Back pressed!");
        }
```

Are you calling below method before the one above?

```
    Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
```

Comment: I also called the setCatchBackKey(true). But it it doesn't work. I'm going to use the isKeyPressed() method and prevent multiple calls by saving the last key state and make only a call when the last key state is different from the current.